# jQuery click function from within another click function

Tags: jquery, html

I have an external JS file that contains the following jQuery code:

```
var globalNames = { next: 'input[name="next"]'};
var globalElements = { next: $e.find(globalNames.next) };

initQuiz: function() {
  globalElements.next.click(function () {

        if (y.forcingQuestionSolve && !j[c.index()] && (y.quizSummeryHide || !y.reviewQustion)) {
            alert(WpProQuizGlobal.questionNotSolved);
            return false
                }
        i.methode.nextQuestion()
     }
);
```

the `globalElements.next.click` function is triggered by a click on a button:

```
<input type="button" name="next" value="Next" class="Button" ">
```

What I would like to do is call this `p.next.click` function from a Input Checkbox click.
I have added the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "input[class='questionInput']", function () {
    alert("Thanks for checking me");
    // This is the line I'm not sure off !?!?
    $('next').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I have tried to call the trigger event but its not working.

I have to note that the 2 jQuery statements are not combined in document, they are separate.

EDIT: Added Correct Variables  (global*)

Comment: Anyone else help?  I'm really struggling with this one.  thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your selector.  `$('next')` just isn't finding anything.

Change this...

```
$('next').trigger('click');
```

to this....

```
$('.Button[name=next]').trigger('click');
```

That will look for an element with the class `Button` and the name `next` and trigger the click event.

You also have a typo in the input element - the last `"` should be a `/`.

Comment: This doesnt work.. nothing happens when clicking the Input Checkbox

Comment: Do you get the alert when you click the checkbox?

Comment: Does the correct code get triggered when you manually click the button?

Comment: when I click the "Next" button, yes It does run the code.

Comment: Okay, there must be something else affecting it then because the code I posted above does trigger that button's click event.  Copy & paste it into the console to see it work.

Comment: I think the issue is something to do with the function  p.next.click(function(   I dont think its getting called from the trigger.

Comment: Without knowing what `p.next` actually is it's not possible to know.  This code will trigger a click event handler for any matching elements.  If `p.next` is a matching element then the `.click()` method *will* be triggered.

Comment: I added the variables to the question.. I might make more sense now

Answer (score 1):

Here is the running solution, please check on running snippet

```js
  $(document).on("click", "input[class='questionInput']", function () {
    alert("Thanks for checking me");
    // This is the line I'm not sure off !?!?
    $('[name="next"]').trigger('click'); 
  });

$('[name="next"]').click(function(){
    console.log("click triggered successfully")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="questionInput" />
<input type="button" name="next" value="NEXT BUTTON" />
```

Comment: this works in your example but not mine.  
I think the issue is that I'm using the following code -

p.next.click(function() {
 
and not $.('[name="next"]').click(function(){